# how to get msgbox when cell value varies exel vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, ms-word

I have a cell "A1" which varies the  integer values from "1 to 150"
suppose if  "A1"cell.Value ="1"  then i should get msgbox containing its  A1 value as "1". 
and 
 if"A1"cell value = "2" then i should get msgbox containing its A1 value as "2"

similarly if A1 value is 3,4,5 and so on, then i should get respective cell value in msgbox 
I wrote a code as seen below. but writing  if code statement ranging from "1 to 150" is dificult task
can anybody minimise thise code adding variables to this.. thank you in advance

```
sub variable()    
    If Range("a1").Value = 1 Then
        MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    Else
        If Range("a1").Value = 2 Then
           MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
        Else
           If Range("a1").Value = 3 Then
               MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value 
           End If
        End If
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you doing it with nested ifs? you could simply write Sub without if statements and each time you run your macro it will tell you value of `range("A1")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to do rewrite the code with `Select Case`:

```
Sub MyVariable()

    Select Case Range("A1").Value
        Case 1 to 150:
            MsgBox Range("A1")
        Case Else:
            'nothing
    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to write this code :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Target.Address = "$A$1") Then
        If (IsNumeric(Target.Value)) Then
            If (Target.Value >= 1 And Target.Value <= 150) Then
                MsgBox Target.Value
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get message each time you enter different value in cell `A1` , then please use code below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim DivRg As Range
Set DivRg = Range("A1")
Set DivRg = Application.Intersect(Target, DivRg)

If DivRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
MsgBox Target
Set DivRg = Nothing

End Sub
```

Please note you should put this code in your `Worksheet` module, not `regular` module.